# How can I ring browser on receiving twilio call

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, twilio

How can I ring on the browser to receive a call on the Twilio number? I'm using .Net core and ReactJS.

```
public TwiMLResult Connect()
    {
        var FromNumber = Request.Form["From"];
        var ToNumber = Request.Form["To"];
        var FireBaseToken = Request.Form["FirebaseToken"];
        var Record = Request.Form["Record"];
        var Digits = Request.Form["Digits"];
        var callingDeviceIdentity = Request.Form["callingDeviceIdentity"];

        Dial.RecordEnum recordEnum = Dial.RecordEnum.RecordFromAnswer;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Record))
        {
            recordEnum = "do-not-record" == Record.ToString().Trim() ? Dial.RecordEnum.DoNotRecord : Dial.RecordEnum.RecordFromAnswer;
        }

        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        string phoneNumber = ToNumber;

        var dial = new Dial(callerId: FromNumber, record: recordEnum,
            recordingStatusCallback: new Uri(_config["BaseUrlApi"] + "api/Call/OuboundCallRecording"),
            recordingStatusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(callingDeviceIdentity))
        {
           // Here I'm receiving a hook from Twilio
        }
```

}

In the if section I can reply 'twiml.Say("Ahoy, World!")' but I want to receive a call here from the browser and build a connection.

Tried this

```
// or handle an incoming call
```

device.on('incoming', call => {});

but unable to trigger this code.

Comment: Do I need to use websocket or any notification app

Answer (score 1):

The [Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript) will allow you to receive and place outgoing calls from the browser.

Twilio provides both a [C# Quickstart](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-csharp) and a [NodeJS Quickstart](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node) github projects with very good documentation to setup and use.

The Twilio Voice JavaScript client will handle the websockets communication between your browser and Twilio.

For reference, this is some example code from the [Twilio.Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliocall) documentation:

```
const device = new Device(token);

// Make an outgoing call
async function makeOutgoingCall() {
  const call = await device.connect();
}

// or handle an incoming call
device.on('incoming', call => {});
```

Comment: Outgoing call is working fine but How can I ring the browser if someone calls our twilio number. do i need to configure in twilio or in c# or i will receive request here directly device.on('incoming', call => {});

Comment: How can i choose or select that this user's browser will ring

Comment: Once the user's client is connected to Twilio and active, your application will need to use Twiml to tell Twilio to Dial the user's client: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client. You can use a Twiml Bin to tell Twilio to dial your user's client upon an inbound phone call.